# Which declaration is causing a unit to be implicitly imported?

Tags: delphi, package

I'm installing some custom components for a project.
I wrote these many years ago so it's a bit fuzzy how things got linked.

I'm getting many warnings like:

> [dcc32 Warning] Life32v2.dpk(53): W1033 Unit 'DDUtils' implicitly imported into package 'Life32v2'

However when I do a Find in files <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for `DDUtils` it is nowhere to be found in the project(group).
Obviously `DDUtils` is used by a unit that **is** explicitly imported by one of my components or the link is even more indirect than that.

Doubleclicking on the error simply takes me to the dpk file which is useless.

Is there a way to see by which route a unit gets imported?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily find the unit that uses it.

Simply find `DDUnit` (`.pas` and/or `.dcu`) on your harddisk and rename it to say, `old_DDUnit.pas` and/or `old_DDUnit.dcu`. Then recompile and the compiler will tell you which unit can't compile because it can't find `DDUnit`.

I usually use the free, excellent and terribly fast [everything.exe](http://voidtools.com) search tool to find any file name or folder on my system.

Of course an IDE tool would be nice, but the above works fine.